# Generic interface implementation

Tags: c#

Let's say we have `GeneralRequest` class with no properties. Every specific request class extends this class. For example:

```
public class GeneralRequest
{
}
```

And:

```
public class UserInsertRequest : GeneralRequest
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class UserUpdateRequest : GeneralRequest
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Also there is interface `IGeneralService` like this:

```
public interface IGeneralService
{
   public Task Insert(GeneralRequest request);
   public Task Update(GeneralRequest request);
}
```

With specific user service interface that implements it:

```
public interface IUsersInterface : GeneralInterface 
{
    public Task FindByFirstName(String FirstName);
}
```

And specific service class that implements it:

```
public class UserService: IUsersInterface 
{
    public async Task Insert(UserInsertRequest request)
    {
      //implementation
    }

    public async Task Update(UserUpdateRequest request)
    {
      //implementation
    }

    public Task FindByFirstName(String FirstName)
    {
      //implementation
    }
}
```

The problem is that `UserService`'s `Insert` and `Update` *is not* `IGeneralService`'s `Insert` and `Update` method implementation (different method signature). But, is there a way to make this logic work?

I tried something like this

```
public interface IGeneralService<T> where T:GeneralRequest
{
   public Task Insert(T request);
   public Task Update(T request);
}
```

But in that case I need to specify the type parameter when implementing IGeneralService, and there are multiple. I'm so confused !

My goal is to have general service interface that every service class implements it, and specific interface for specific service class.

Comment: Your generic approach at the bottom looks reasonable - I don't know what oyu mean by "But in that case I need to specify the type parameter when implementing IGeneralService, and there are multiple." You'd have `public class UserService : IGeneralService<UserRequest>` (or make `IUserService` derive from `IGeneralService<UserRequest>`).

Comment: @JonSkeet Well when I implement ` IGeneralService ` it would look something like this: ` public class UsersService: IGeneralService<X> ` X extends GeneralRequest, but there can be UserInsertRequest, UserUpdateRequest etc ... I want to be able to use them all.

Comment: Do you intend to have one service per request type? or is a service intended to handle all types of requests? If the former you would typically have some type of resolution mechanism to find the correct service for your specific type of request. If the later you cannot use the request object in your service without inserting runtime checks, and that is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Okay, so you need to make it generic in two type parameters - one for insert and one for update. But it's pretty unclear to me what the benefit of this would be, to be honest.

Comment: as @JonasH mentioned. I need service intended to handle all types of requests.

Comment: ... all types of requests _regarding a certain entity type_. Right?

Comment: @Fildor exactly. Service that handles all types of requests for every entity. Basically, it has Insert/Update/DeleteRequests. But every one of those requests are different for different entities. So User has FirstName and Last name for insert, but let's say entity Role would have RoleName, RoleId etc ...

Comment: Have you considered the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)? That should allow you to achieve multiple dispatch, i.e. define one method for each combination of request and service types.

Comment: @JonasH I'm not familiar with this pattern. But I will take a look, thanks :)

Comment: If every entity has to be handled differently, then what is the generalization good for? Do they in fact have anything in common apart from wanting to insert/delete/update "something". I guess in the end it will boil down to what EF / EF Core is already giving you as an API... (if you are using one of those)

Comment: Unrelated: `public Task Insert(GeneralRequest request);` => I'd recommend to do `public Task InsertAsync(GeneralRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);` from the Get-Go.